# Alfresco integration with Kofax

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, kofax

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0.b and I have to integrate it with Kofax. I have googled, but I couldn't find any Alfresco's solution available for community users. Am I missing something?
Any advice on best way to do that will be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/kofax-install.html

Comment: @Krutik Jayswal , thank you very much for your answer, I tried but I couldn't log in to Support Portal to download the file for instalation. I have to be Alfresco partner for that? Unfortunately, my licence has expired few months ago, and I'm using community edicion.

Comment: The [Kofax page on Alfresco Add-Ins](https://addons.alfresco.com/tags/kofax) suggests that the connector is a paid-for extra, so I suspect you're going to need to ring up Alfresco Sales and renew your contract....

Comment: If you have Kofax, you can use their CMIS connector which doesn't need an Enterprise version of Alfresco.